# How to run observer if no result from forkJoin?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I need to run observer if after one second there is no result from forkJoin:

```
 of().pipe(delay(1000), skipUntil(!forkJoin$))
.subscribe(());
```

It does not work for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timeoutWith()`:

```
forkJoin([timer(500), timer(750)]).pipe(
  timeoutWith(1000, of('Hi')),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Try changing `timer()` delays.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-v2jmu8?devtoolsheight=60